# Returning multiple results when searching a tree in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, binary-tree

I have a school project that is requiring me to build a Database Emulator in JAVA which contains a school course catalog.

I have everything working but the search. The search method is required to search through the Index first (which is a BSTree ADT) and return an array of ints (the indexes to the full row data in the database array) if any were found.

If you are familiar with SQL jargon, I only need to support search queries that mimic the 'LIKE' specifier in SQL which is this, "LIKE 'Intro%'", it could return multiple results matching the predicate "Intro".

Is there a way to do this recursively like when traversing the Tree inOrder like this?

Here was my first-draft attempt:

```
public int[] select(IndexNode localRoot, String selectQuery, int[] resultSet) {

    if (localRoot != null) {
        resultSet = select(localRoot.getLeftChild(), selectQuery, resultSet);

        // get the nth number of characters from the data
        String thisResult = localRoot.getData().substring(0, selectQuery.length());

        // and compare it to the searchQuery
        if (selectQuery.compareToIgnoreCase(thisResult) == 0)
            // add this current local root's index to the return int array

        resultSet = select(localRoot.getRightChild(), selectQuery, resultSet);

    } // End root not null

    return resultSet;
} // End select() method
```

Comment: I suggest you pass a list to your tree search method. Whenever you get a value that matches your criteria, add it to the list. In the end, you can return the list or convert the list to an Array an return it.

Comment: Like an ArrayList? Or a LinkedList?

Comment: An arraylist would work. You could also use a LinkedList BTW.